# mod_rewrite with unknown amount of directories

Tags: mod-rewrite

I know how to make mod_rewarite if I know how many directories I will have like `site.com/page/page1/page2 etc` .. But is there a way to make somehow rewrite if I don't know how many `/page/...` will be?

Comment: Where should your rule rewrite to ? Give a real example

Comment: I will have script which will browse directories but I will not know which category how many sub-category will have. They will be created dinamically. Or I don't understand your question?

Comment: Do you need to capture some directories separately or do you pass entire URI to rewrite page ?

Comment: I will pass entire URI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your htaccess is in root folder (like your `script.php` file)

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /script.php?uri=$1 [L]
```

You can get the result in `script.php` with `$_GET['uri']`.

*script.php*

```
<?php echo $_GET['uri']; ?>
```

Example: `http://domain.com/page/page1/page2`
Result you can see: **page/page1/page2**

Comment: I think you don't understand me or I didn't writed clear enough. I need exact opposite from `/script.php?uri=page/page1/page2` to `http://domain.com/page/page1/page2`

Comment: Well with my code you can now go to `http://domain.com/page/page1/page2`. Isn't it what you wanted ?

Comment: In your example is from `http://domain.com/page/page1/page2` to `/script.php?uri=page/page1/page2`.. I want it in other way from `/script.php?uri=page/page1/page2` to `http://domain.com/page/page1/page2`

Comment: You didn't understand my answer. With my code, you now have the possibility to reach `http://domain.com/page/page1/page2` which will be **internally rewritten** to `script.php`. Try it and you'll understand (i edited my answer to be clearer)

Comment: Ok, I will try it. And this will rewrite whenever deep in sub-directory I need?

Comment: This will rewrite everything (except existing files/folders), no matter how much sub you have